# Generators for commutator subgroup of surface group

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

Let $\pi_1(\Sigma_g) = \langle\text{$x_1,\ldots,x_{2g}$ $|$ $[x_1,x_2]\cdots[x_{2g-1},x_{2g}]$}\rangle$ be a surface group.  Can anyone tell me an explicit free basis for the commutator subgroup of $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$?  I would prefer one consisting of conjugates of the elementary commutators $[x_i,x_j]$.

Comment: See the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577016/set-of-generators-of-the-commutator-subgroup-of-a-surface-group).

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I hadn't seen that question, but the comments don't look like they contain any nontrivial information.

Comment: I know, but they contain some "nontrivial" suggestions, which you can follow.

Comment: Here's a recipe.  The commutator subgroup $F'$ of the free group $F=\langle x_1,\ldots,x_{2g}\rangle$ is freely generated by the conjugates of the commutators of the basis elements. (This is proved in Serre's book *Trees*.)   An (infinite) presentation for $G'$ is then obtained from $F'$ by quotienting out by the (infinitely many) conjugates   in $F$ of the relator.  Each of those conjugates enables you to eliminate one basis element from $F'$, so with a bit of care, one can write down a basis for $G'.$

Comment: @HJRW: I think you must have a typo or something in your 1st sentence: the conjugates of commutators of basis elements generate $F'$, but they are not a free basis -- if they were, then they would project to a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for the abelianization $[F,F]^{\text{ab}}$ and it would follow that this abelianization is a free $\mathbb{Z}[F_n]$-module (while in fact the $F_n$-action descends to an action of $\mathbb{Z}^n$; what is more, it is not even a free $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}^n]$-module).  Can you give me the precise reference in Serre's book so I can figure out what you are trying to say?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: The only real mathematical content in those comments is the suggestion to use Reidemeister-Schreier (i.e. brute-force combinatorial group theory), which in this case will give you a terrible and messy presentation for the commutator subgroup.  I doubt it will even make it obvious that this commutator subgroup is a free group.

Comment: @Linda, I don't have the book in front of me, but my memory (from over 10 years ago!) is that a basis for $F'$ is explained.  I think perhaps you've misunderstood what I mean by "conjugates of commutators": I just meant the conjugates by representatives of the elements of $\mathbb{Z}^n=F/F'$. At least when $n=2$, it's geometrically clear that these form a basis: this is just saying that $\pi_1$ of the square grid is freely generated by the unit squares.   Apologies for being unclear. I may have access to *Trees* on Monday, and if so I'll try to find the reference.

Comment: @HJRW: I see!  It is true that for $n=2$ these form a basis, but I don't think this is true for higher $n$.  The issue is that $[F,F]^{\text{ab}}$ is not a free $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}^n]$-module for $n \geq 3$.  There are a lot of ways to see this; one easy one is to use the fact that $H_k(\mathbb{Z}^n;[F_n,F_n]^{\text{ab}}) \cong \wedge^{k+2} \mathbb{Z}^n$ together with the fact that if $M$ if a free $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module, then $H_k(G;M)=0$ for $k \geq 1$.

Comment: nb: to see that $H_k(\mathbb{Z}^n;[F_n,F_n]^{\text{ab}}) \cong \wedge^{k+2} \mathbb{Z}^n$, simply use the fact that the spectral sequence for the extension $1 \rightarrow [F_n,F_n] \rightarrow F_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow 1$ has to degenerate to give the homology of $F_n$, so all of the differentials have to be isomorphisms.

Comment: @Linda, I suspect a more direct way to see that they’re not a basis for $n>2$ is just to invoke the Hall—Witt identity. (After all, it gives a relation between the faces of a cube.) Perhaps Serre only deals with the $n=2$ case.

Comment: I note that the comments to the MSE question contain a link to a question that does give a free basis for the $F_n'$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184176/commutator-subgroup-of-a-free-group .  Using that, my suggestion shouldn't be hard to implement: since the relators lift to embedded 2-cells in the corresponding cover, each can be used to eliminate exactly one generator.

Comment: @HJRW: I think that's the same basis you get by using one of the obvious maximal trees in the appropriate cover.  I've tried in the past to do what you suggest, but it quickly becomes a mess to express each conjugate of the surface relation in terms of the basis.  It's not clear that as you eliminate one generator at a time you don't end up screwing up later eliminations.  It's definitely not the case that the words in the basis corresponding to the different conjugates of the surface relation are disjoint, and their overlaps become really complicated as you start eliminating generators.

Comment: (but what you suggest is what I planned to try if no one gives me an answer to this question)

Comment: @Linda, of course it's what you get by contracting a maximal tree -- what else could it be!?   Good luck -- I still think that's the correct strategy.

Answer (score 8):

Before I answer this old question, a confession: the user "Linda" is actually me!  I asked this basically to make sure that something I proved was not already known.  This is such a classical subject that you can never be sure!

Anyway, I finally got around to writing up a paper that among other things answers this question.  It can be downloaded [here](https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/papers/Commutator.pdf).  Theorem B of it shows that the commutator subgroup of a surface group is freely generated by the set

$$\{\text{$[x_i,x_j]^{x_i^{k_i} \cdots x_{2g}^{k_{2g}}}$ $|$ $1 \leq i<j \leq 2g$, $(i,j) \neq (1,2)$, and $k_i,\ldots,k_{2g} \in \mathbb{Z}$}\}$$

Here I'm using superscripts to indicate conjugation: $a^b = b^{-1} a b$.

This should be compared to a theorem of Tomaszewski that says that the commutator subgroup of a free group $F_n$ on $n$ generators $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ is freely generated by the set

$$\{\text{$[x_i,x_j]^{x_i^{k_i} \cdots x_{n}^{k_{n}}}$ $|$ $1 \leq i<j \leq n$, and $k_i,\ldots,k_{n} \in \mathbb{Z}$}\}$$

In other words, when you impose the surface relation to go from $F_{2g}$ to the surface group, you have to just omit the conjugates of $[x_1,x_2]$.  I give a new proof of Tomaszewski's theorem in my paper as well (see Theorem A).